# How can I access file by inode on Linux

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, kernel, ext4

is there any userspace API or third-party kernel module that can help to access file by inode on Linux?

I'm trying to implement something like:

```
int read_file_by_ino(int ino, int pos, int size, char* buf);
int write_file_by_ino(int ino, int pos, int size, const char* buf);
int readdir_by_ino(...);
int stat_by_ino(...);
...
```

The program is expected to run under root user, so there's no security requirement to do permission checking.

Comment: Probably not, and why do you ask? It looks like a reliability nightmare. So it is certainly **a bad idea**

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm implementing a fuse program, which needs to operate remote filesystem, the fuse low-level API works with i-node number. However, fuse high-level API works with path, but I think that there will be some performance loss.

Comment: Nice answer with rationale "why?" : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36092651/544721

Answer (score 3):

I found the question connected concerning similar topic [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35292/quickly-find-which-files-belongs-to-a-specific-inode-number).

Summarizing, check out those commands:

- `find /path/to/mountpoint -inum <inode number>`
- `sudo debugfs -R 'ncheck 393094' /dev/sdaX 2>/dev/null`

Hope this helps you investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your problem correctly but:
You can start with "/" directory and proceed recursively (or any loop for that matter) with children. Compare the inode value with `strcut stat.ino_t`. Once you find it, open the path/file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is an easier way or not but you can do this with bash. with ls -i command you can see the inodes too,

```
$ ls -i
11147622 file.txt
```

the first column is the inode number, the blow command shows the inodes in current directory

```
$ ls -i | awk {'print $1'}
```

so you need to check the inodes from / too all it's subdirectories until find it

```
ls -iR /
```

it shows all subdirectories and there files with there inode number

now you should start from / and use awk to or cut command to have the first column(inode number is in the first column) then compare it with the inode you want to find.