# Open file by inode

Tags: linux, filesystems, stdio

Is it possible to open a file knowing its inode?

```
ls -i /tmp/test/test.txt
529965 /tmp/test/test.txt
```

I can provide path, inode (above 529965) and I am looking to get in return a file descriptor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't files be manipulated by inode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606774/why-cant-files-be-manipulated-by-inode)

Answer (score 28):

This is not possible because it would open a loophole in the access control rules.  Whether you can open a file depends not only on *its own* access permission bits, but on the permission bits of every containing directory.  (For instance, in your example, if `test.txt` were mode 644 but the containing directory `test` were mode 700, then only `root` and the owner of `test` could open `test.txt`.)  Inode numbers only identify the file, not the containing directories (it's possible for a file to be in more than one directory; read up on "hard links") so the kernel cannot perform a complete set of access control checks with only an inode number.

(Some Unix implementations have offered nonstandard root-only APIs to open a file by inode number, bypassing some of the access-control rules, but if current Linux has such an API, I don't know about it.)

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly what you are asking, but (as hinted by [zwol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388520/zwol)) both Linux and NetBSD/FreeBSD provide the ability to open files using previously created “handles”: These are inode-like persistent names that identify a file on a file system.

On *BSD ([`getfh`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getfh&sektion=2) and [`fhopen`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fhopen&sektion=2)) using this is as simple as:

```c
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>


fhandle_t file_handle;
getfh("<file_path>", &file_handle);  // Or `getfhat` for the *at-style API

// … possibly save handle as bytes somewhere and recreate it some time later …

int fd = fhopen(&file_handle, O_RDWR);
```

The last call requiring the caller to be root however.

The Linux [`name_to_handle_at`](https://man.cx/name_to_handle_at(2)) and [`open_by_handle_at`](https://man.cx/open_by_handle_at(2)) system calls are similar, but a lot more explicit and require the caller to keep track of the relevant file system mount IDs/UUIDs themselves, so I'll humbly link to the [detailed example in the manpage](https://man.cx/name_to_handle_at(2)#heading9) instead. Beware, that the example is not complete if you are looking to persist the handles across reboots; one has to convert the received mount ID to a persistent filesystem identifier, such as a filesystem UUID, and convert that back to a mount ID later on. In essence they do the same however. And just like on *BSD using the later system call requires elevated privileges (*CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH* to be exact).

Comment: This is really cool and useful for so many things. TIL, thanks for sharing!